How to attach a 4x8 plywood to a air hockey table
I have a 4x8 plywood with walls around the corners built using 2x4. It's very heavy. Kids are going to build structures using Lego on the plywood tabletop. I want to place the tabletop on top of something so kids can stand and work on it. I have a air hockey table approximately 3ft x 6ft that I am hoping to use by placing tabletop on it. One problem with this approach is tabletop can begin to slide and move around as kids lean on it. So the question is, how to affix tabletop to the air hockey table so the tabletop wouldnt move and when the season is over I can remove the tabletop and store it away. I thought of velcro stripes mot sure if they would be strong enough to attach. Are there other options ?



Note that unless the plywood is stiffened somehow (usually with battens on the underside) it is likely to sag.

Add a skirt, e.g 3/4" plywood strips, to the bottom of the panel that is just large enough to surround the top of air hockey table to prevent sliding. It's a simple matter to lift the top off and set it aside.
Note that this assumes that the table is heavy enough and the kids light enough that playing on the maximum 1 foot of overhang will not cause the table to flip off the air hockey table. If that is not the case then you'll need a positive hold down of some sort to ensure that everything falls over together. That might be as simple as screw eyes on the corners of the skirt tied to the legs of the air hockey table.

i love the idea. it's brilliant. can I use furring strips to build the skirt ?  I am deciding between glueing vs screwing. With screws ,I can remove the skirt if for whatever reason, but I will have to deal with screw holes. Glueing makes it bit harder to attach and remove if needed but no holes to deal with. any thoughts ?

If everything is sufficiently flat and stiff you could get by with L-shaped bits that just capture the corners of the air hockey table, perhaps 6 inches on a side. I would want something at least 1/2" thick, so your furring strips should suffice. Screws into solid wood should be fine. If you want to make the pieces removable/replaceable you could use small carriage bolts through the top with washers and nuts on the bottom, though that would leave through-holes in the top.

@Siva I'd glue or use carefully countersunk screws, so the top surface is flat for playing on.  Screw head sticking up would be annoying

couldn't multiple kids on one edge of the table cause it to tip over?

I like this idea... but would recommend sticking some bolts with wingnuts and a cross piece or two too securely attach the tabletop so that your kiddos don't hurt themselves... You would be surprised what kids can tip over.

can you tell me more? are you saying drive bolts into hockey table through tabletop.?

@ Siva I think what @Questor meant was very long bolts (or maybe even studding/threaded rod) used to attach a clamp bar under the table. A webbing strap and picture-hanging hardware coudl do something similar.  But I'd be more likely to make a frame that sits snugly round the air hockey table on all 8 sides, tall enough that the new cover can only come off vertically, and not tip.  But that takes more tools and design.

@ChrisH yeah, I wasn't suggesting doing anything that would damage the air hockey table. If that was on the table case some screws or glue would be easier.

The frame Idea would work, but it takes a bit more design/work to make it fit snuggly on the air hockey (so the surface doesn't wiggle). compared to a couple of bar clamps which are adjustable.

EDIT:  The answer now has a pic of the air hockey table. I've never seen one that's not rectangular.  The shape of the table shouldn't really affect my answer other than the pic is less accurate--but the concept is the same.
HABO's edge idea is still better.
Velcro should be enough
I Do like HABO's idea, and it's unquestionably more comprehensive than velcro strips.
However, considering a 4x8 sheet of plywood's weight--I'd bet good money that velcro around the edges would be plenty enough to keep it in place.
In fact, I'd start with only around 6" of velcro at each corner, since velcro the full length may render the plywood extremely difficult to remove.
Of course, aligning the velcro is key to it working properly, and the velcro adhesive may damage the table's finish--then again a heavy sheet of wood won't exactly polish the table anyway.
:,)
Something along these lines.  In this example, the black is the velcro.


I'd use far less velcro to start with.  And it needs to be stuck down very well.  Actual veclro is often stronger than its glue, if the surface is slightly textured (like ply) and pulled straight off rather than peeled.  Velcro would actually work better if there wasn't a lip round the edge and the ply could flex

Good point.  And I see there's an update to the shape of the table.  I'll amend my answer.
